# invalid bash line in gitlab, but unclear why

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I am attempting to parse the nodejs package.json for the version number.. this line usually works but somehow I am now getting an error of invalid block

```
PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g' | xargs)
```

specifically this area is highlighted in VSCode `sed 's/......`

[image]

How can I repair this line?  is the `"` needing escaping or ?

Comment: Is it actually broken? Or just a syntax highlighting fail? Nothing wrong with that `sed` expression

Comment: gitlab complains on the line

Comment: I'm guessing it's the space after `$(cat`, try quoting the whole command substitution like you did for BRANCH_NAME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is YAML-related (it seems the combination of `:` and `|` is the culprit).

The easy fix is to use a YAML block:

```yaml
script:
  # …
  - |-
    PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g' | xargs)
```

And while you’re at it you can use a folding block to make it more readable:

```yaml
script:
  # …
  - >-
    PACKAGE_VERSION=$(
      cat package.json |
      grep version |
      head -1 |
      awk -F: '{ print $2 }' |
      sed 's/[",]//g' |
      xargs
    )
```

<sup>Chaining `grep`, `head`, `awk` and `sed` can usually be replaced by a single `awk`. And there’s a [useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). Not to mention parsing JSON without a proper JSON parser.</sup>